# Attach tooltip to just the div with class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to attach the tooltip just the div with the class `hello`, if I hover over the span, the tooltip is getting attached to the span element and its just stuck over there and not getting destroyed.
What am I missing here

```
<div class="hello">
    Hello
    <span class="world ui-icon ui-icon-save"></span>
</div>

$('.hello').hover(function(e){
    $(this).tooltip({
        content: function(callback) {
            callback("hello");   
        },
        items: '*'
    }).tooltip("open");
}, function() {
    $(this).tooltip('destroy');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/06exbwdv/)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thank you for providing a fiddle

Secondly, the Tooltip initialization code apply's mouseover/mouseleave events to the element so you don't need to embed it in a "hover" method

And if you wish to only show the Tooltip once, then destroy it so it will not show again, use the Close method i.e.

```
$('.hello').tooltip({
    content: function(callback) {
        callback("hello");   
    },
    items: '*',
    close: function( event, ui ) {
         $( this ).tooltip( "destroy" );
    }
})
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/n8kjdzgc/ for working example

Comment: @i want it to be shown multiple times as i hover over it. When I move out it should be destroyed, on mouse enter, it tooltip should be populated

Comment: I just want the tooltip to be attached to div, not to the span element inside div

Comment: Why does it need to be destroyed? if your wanting to repopulate the content on open, use the Open event(Same syntax as Close event in my example). $('.hello').tooltip() is attaching it to the Div not the Span, Im not sure what you mean by that